# What is the value of $\sum_{|A|=r}\{\textrm{min}(A)\}=k?$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $S=\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$ be a set of first $n$ natural numbers. A subset $A$ of set $S$ is formed by choosing the elements from the set $S$. Suppose $|A|$ represents the cardinality of the set $A$ and $\textrm{min}(A)$ represents the least number among the elements of the set $A$. For example, if $A=\{5,6,7\}$ then $\textrm{min}(A)=5.$ The value of $$\sum_{|A|=r}\{\textrm{min}(A)\}=k$$ is

---

## Options:

$\displaystyle1.)\:\:n\cdot\binom{n-k}{r-1}$

$\displaystyle2.)\:\:(n+1)\cdot\binom{n-k}{r-1}-r\cdot\binom{n-k+1}{r}$

$\displaystyle3.)\:\:k\cdot\binom{n-k}{r-1}+n\cdot\binom{n-k+1}{r}$

$\displaystyle4.)\:\:\binom{n}{r}$

---

I can easily do this question if the value of $r$ is $2$. In that case the value of $k$ will be $\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)(n-1)n}{6}$. But here, I am not able to understand how the $k$ came in options. Also, in my opinion the answer should be $$\binom{n-1}{r-1}+2\cdot\binom{n-2}{r-1}+3\cdot\binom{n-3}{r-1}+\cdots+(r-1)\binom{r-1}{r-1}$$ but I'm pretty sure that it's not correct.

---

The answer given in my textbook is option $2$. No theory has been given in it, regarding this question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does k appear both as the wanted quantity and in the options?

Comment: @insipidintegrator even I am not understanding that

Comment: Attach a picture maybe?

Comment: @insipidintegrator the question was just this....but for you I'll attach the picture...my phone is not available right now..i'll do it asap

Comment: @insipidintegrator can you pls tell the value of $k$ in terms of $n$ and $r$...leave the options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

> $\sum_{|A|=r}\{\textrm{min}(A)\}=k$

seems to be nonsense. At least, I do  not see how to interpret it, and I see no way that this could be a function of $k$.

---

However, you seem to be asking for the answer to this question:

> What is $\sum_{|A|=r}\min(A)$?

Your expression is almost correct, except for the final term.
$$
\binom{n-1}{r-1}+2\cdot\binom{n-2}{r-1}+3\cdot\binom{n-3}{r-1}+\cdots+(\color{red}{n-r+1})\binom{r-1}{r-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-r+1}i\binom{n-i}{r-1}
$$
We can simplify this as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-r+1}i\binom{n-i}{r-1}
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-r+1} (n+1)\binom{n-i}{r-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-r+1}(n-i+1)\binom{n-i}{r-1}
\\&=(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n-r+1} \binom{n-i}{r-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-r+1}r\binom{n-i+1}{r}
\\&=(n+1)\binom nr-r\sum_{i=1}^{n-r+1}\binom{n-i+1}{r}
\\&=(r+1)\binom{n+1}{r+1}-r\binom{n+1}{r+1}
\\&=\binom{n+1}{r+1}
\end{align}
$$
We made use of the identity $k\binom mk=m\binom {m-1}{k-1}$ twice, and used the hockey stick identity to eliminate all summations.

---

Of course, the simple and beatiful identity $$\sum_{|A|=r}\min(A)=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$ should also have a combinatorial proof, and indeed it does, which I invite the interested reader to try and find.

Comment: shouldn't the upper bound on all the summations be $n-r+1?$

Comment: Either $n$ or $n-r+1$ is fine; making the upper bound $n$ adds additional terms, but these are all zero.

Comment: oh...i see....can you pls show the working of $n-r+1$ also?